# ins_sqlplus.mk Error in invoking target 'install' of makefile

Tags: oracle, ubuntu-16.04, oracle12c

I'm installing oracle on my machine (Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS).
I followed this tutorial completely http://www.techienote.com/install-oracle-12c-on-ubuntu/, however I have an error Error in invoking target 'install' of makefile in ins_sqlplus.mk file.

I searched everywhere but I did not find anything about it, if someone could help me about

yes my has all package.
which I believe to be necessary

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems here:

1.)  Ubuntu is not a supported platform for Oracle.

2.)  The tutorial you're following is for Ubuntu 15.04, but you're on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS.

I recommend *not* running Oracle on Ubuntu (or any other unsupported OS).  Try using VirtualBox to run Oracle Linux, and run Oracle there.

That way, you still can keep your Ubuntu 16.04.4 environment, but you have Oracle Linux 7 to run Oracle 12c inside of it.

-Mark